# ADB - failure of installing apk on android device that has 0.00b internal storage while it has free space?

Tags: android, adb, busybox

I have changed my I9070 firmware and the Internal Storage 0.00B and can't install apps and save files.

In order to fix the problem I have tried to install busy box but not succeeded.

```
c:\adb>adb devices
List of devices attached
C074114C31720D21CD73F6306E34174 device


c:\adb>adb shell
$ su
# su
# exit
# exit
$ exit

c:\adb>adb install busybox.apk
3264 KB/s (2679743 bytes in 0.801s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/busybox.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

Is there any help regarding this or other option?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states it didnot have enough memory for installation either increase memory or delete some data and then try.
Thank you

Comment: The phone is fresh and not installed any app. The main problem is that showing 0.00B Internal storage. SDCARD is normally shows the size of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install any app with 0B. 
Now to your issue im not sure why the internal memory is 0B. either you format your device and see,or restart and check if it changes

Fix From Another Post
I found a solution, hopefully this can help someone in the future
The problem was i installed busybox using an installer which causing some file discrepancies.

To fix it :
1. Install Android Terminal Emulator, this app can be installed even if storage shows full. If you cant install the terminal use Uniflashv2 (open uniflashv2 and connect your device with the debug usb on, go to rom modding, then file manager)

2. copy /system/xbin/busybox to /system/bin, if busybox is installed the code is "busybox cp /system/xbin/busybox to /system/bin"
3. power off then power on (reboot)

When I did the above, all my previous apps and setting came back to normal

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1720053)

Comment: I know that with 0B or 0.00k cannot to install and save anything. But my phone problem is not the actual 0B but it has more than 1gb free space, but it shows 0.00b. Some forum suggested to copy the busybox.apk to xbin folder but I tried more and can't to succeed that. any help?